# Impossible to get Wifi to work on Lenovo X201 tablet after Windows reinstallation

Tags: laptop, drivers, lenovo-laptop

I've reinstalled Windows 7 32 bits a year ago on my X201 tablet, and since then I have NEVER been able to get the Wifi to work again. I've been using a cheap router set in Client mode via Ethernet, which works fine (I have network and internet access), but I've had enough of packing all these bits and bobs around with me.

I have tried installing every WAN and WLAN driver listed [here](http://www.lenovo-driver.com/lenovo-drivers/lenovo-thinkpad-x201-tablet-drivers-download), downloaded from Lenovo's website, but the only network connections listed are "Local Area Connection" and "Bluetooth Network Connection". Device manager flags that "Network Controller", "PCI serial port", "PCI simple communications controller" and "Unknown device" do not have drivers installed (under "other devices"). Lenovo does not have any ISO of driver DVD available, which I found ludicrous.

I'm out of options, any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? On [Lenovo's Support site](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-tablet-laptops/thinkpad-x201-tablet?beta=false) I spotted some Qualcomm WAN drivers that were not listed on the site you linked.

Comment: 7, 32 bits. I remember installing a qualcomm as well a few months back, can't remember which one it was.

Comment: This is the most up-to-date Qualcomm [WAN driver](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-tablet-laptops/thinkpad-x201-tablet/downloads/DS001302) for Windows 32-bit for your laptop.

Comment: Here is the [LAN driver](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-tablet-laptops/thinkpad-x201-tablet/downloads/DS012870) too.

Comment: Did you use the lenovo X201 recovery software/discs to install W7?

Comment: No, but I used a driver utility to reinstall all drivers, and as root says, the wifi LED is never lit, nor is it blinking, ever. So the card must be broken...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed dozens of x201 series laptops and can say I have not seen a more consistent rate of problems with wifi adapters than with this specific series.

In most cases, the internal wifi antenna is damaged/defective and must be replaced. A good indicator of this is when the green wifi symbol will not light up (and the bluetooth symbol is lit), or having the wifi light turn off shortly after enabling wifi (`Fn+F5`).

[image]

Of course, make sure the main wifi switch is set correctly and that you enable all wireless radios with `Fn+F5`. The switch is on the left hand side of the laptop and on the end closest to the user.

I have had occasional success by uninstalling the wifi network adapter from Computer Management, which forces the laptop to reidentify the adapater on next boot.

Lenovo has suggested running their ThinkVantage System Update tool for *all* available updates (critical/required/optional). They have insisted that some updates that claim to install merely defer when not all available updates are selected. I can't speak to the validity of this, mostly because it sounds like a support filler statement, but it may be worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it sounds like it's nearly the end of the tunnel one way or the other. The Wifi indicator is never lit, whereas I can light up or switch off the bluetooth indicator with the hard switch on the left hand side. FN+F5 has no effect. I don't know where I can uninstall the wifi network adapter (it's not listed in the network adapters!) so I uninstalled the unknown "Network Controller" and restarted but the computer says it's failed to install a generic driver. I'll run the automatic driver update tool tonight, but it does sound like the antenna's gone right?

Comment: Sounds as though we aren't certain that the unidentified device you uninstalled was really the wireless adapter. In that case I would look for other likely candidates. If the laptop can't do a basic load of the adapter after uninstalling it and rebooting, there is likely a hardware issue. You mentioned you have owned this laptop for some time, but I would check it's warantee status. Lenovo has come on site in the past to replace the hardware and can provide the same service (if covered) for home users.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same (even a bit bigger) problem after setting an X201 back to factory status. 
I went to Lenovo support website http://support.lenovo.com/de/en/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/ThinkPad-X-Series-laptops/ThinkPad-X201/3626/AC9?tabName=Downloads&linkTrack=Mast:SubNav:Support:Drivers%20and%20Software|Drivers%20and%20Software&beta=false
and after I typed in my serial number (without the dash) I was then able to download ethernet and wireless controller and driver. Since I didn't know which was the correct one I took all 5 and simply installed them ... number 2 and 4 did it for me. Everything working now!